# How to bind element Content to custom Command property

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a custom ICommand class, to which I am trying to add properties "DisplayName" and "ToolTipText":

```
internal class MyCommand : ICommand
{
// ...
        internal string DisplayName {
            get { return displayName; }
            set {
                if (displayName == value)
                    return;
                if (value == null)
                    value = "";
                displayName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(DisplayName));
            }
        }

        internal string ToolTipText {
            get { return toolTipText; }
            set {
                if (toolTipText == value)
                    return;
                if (value == null)
                    value = "";
                toolTipText = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ToolTipText));
            }
        }
// ...
}
```

My ViewModel returns the custom type for the ICommand:

```
    public MyCommand MyButtonCommand {
        get {
            return myButtonCommand?? (myButtonCommand = new MyCommand (
            // ...
            );
        }
    }
```

in XAML, I bind the command to a Button, and I want to set the button Content from the DisplayName on the Command. As requested in the answer, the button binding is this:

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Margin="12,0,0,0" DockPanel.Dock="Right" TabIndex="10"
        Command="{Binding MyButtonCommand, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

The following produces a result:

```
Content="{Binding Command, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

This way, the button's Content is ToString() on the Command. But I can't access properties on the custom ICommand object.

XAML syntax like these do not work:

```
Content="{Binding Command.DisplayName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"

Content="{Binding Command/DisplayName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

Any answers?

... Now answered: my DisplayName and ToolTipText properties only needed to be made public ...

Comment: How is the command bound in the first place? Can't you just bind to the property directly, i.e. `MyButtonCommand.DisplayName`? Please provide a good [mcve] that shows clearly how your code is configured. I don't know if it will help here, but earlier this year I wrote up a technique for generalizing this scenario, i.e. to provide UI text for your own `ICommand` instead of using `RoutedUICommand`. You might want to take a look: http://blogs.msmvps.com/duniho/2016/03/03/global-command-binding-the-less-attractive-options/

Comment: and the class and properties must be public not internal

Comment: Yes: as answered, the issue was nothing more than making the properties public (just an omission on my part really). I can add that the classes do not need to be public: all of my ViewModels and contained classes are internal. Any properties to expose to the View are public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following xaml are both working

the classical, standard one

```
Content="{Binding MyButtonCommand.DisplayName}" Command="{Binding MyButtonCommand}"
```

the quite unusual

```
`Content="{Binding Command.DisplayName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Command="{Binding MyButtonCommand}`"
```

assuming that both MyCommand and DisplayName are **public** and **not** internal

```
  public class MyCommand : ICommand
    {
        public string DisplayName
```

and that DisplayName has a value...

Comment: That was the only issue: my properties were internal! The binding to Self with Command.DisplayName works as expected ... Do you have any further comments on why you think this one is "unusual"? To me it seemed appropriate since it will always be bound to the local command ... (And BTW, the CLASSES do not need to be public: only the properties exposed to the view.)

Comment: @StevenCoco ok, thank you... it was only my *personal opinion* (based on what I've seen and my preferences), sorry *nothing really objective*. (btw ... for the keeps, please edit your question to include your command binding, thank you again)